# Does InfoBright package come with Mysql?

Tags: mysql, infobright

I followed the instruction from https://www.infobright.org/index.php/ICE_Wiki/wiki-4/installation/install-guide-for-linux/ . After installing InfoBright using dpkg, I run:

```
ps aux|grep mysqld
/usr/bin/mysql-ib
```

Definitely no mysqld is running, so can't connect to mysql.

Then I installed mysql-server using apt-get, and reinstalled InfoBright Community Edition using dpkg.
This time I could connect to mysql server, however I can't see the infobright engine.

```
show engines;
```

The engine list shown below

```
FEDERATED
MRG_MYISAM
BLACKHOLE
MyISAM
MEMORY
ARCHIVE
InnoDB
PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
```

Could anybody tell me how to integrate InfoBright with mysql?

Answer (score 1):

InfoBright operates on the BRIGHTHOUSE engine, and cannot be used in conjunction with an installation that utilizes the InnoDB engine (There's some sort of build restriction with MySQL). Even though you can't use InnoDB, you can still use MyISAM.

After installation, you will need to run: `/etc/init.d/mysqld-ib start` to get the mysqld running.

Side note: InfoBright runs, by default, on port 5029, as opposed to the default MySQL port of 3306.